# Setting itemController on a filtered subset of an ArrayController's model

Tags: ember.js

Problem Summary: While I can get the children of a collection (defined on an ArrayController) to use a specific object controller for the individuals, this doesn't work on filtered subsets of the children.

Short context: I've got Subcriptions, which have Items. I'd like to filter the subscriptions in my view by type, and have the items within those subscriptions sort by timestamp. Here's the SubscriptionsController:

```
Social.SubscriptionsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'subscription',

  announcements: function() {
     return this.get('model').filterBy('kind', 'announcement');
  }.property('model.@each.kind'),

  user_sites: function() {
    return this.get('model').filterBy('kind', 'user');
  }.property('model.@each.kind')
});
```

I've defined SubscriptionController thusly:

```
Social.SubscriptionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  items: function() {
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
      sortProperties: ['post_timestamp'],
      sortAscending: false,
      content: this.get('content.items')
    });
  }.property('content.items'),
});
```

And here's the relevant bit of my handlebars template:

```
{{#each controller}}
  <li>{{controller.description}} {{controller.kind}} {{controller.feed_url}} {{controller.base_url}}</li>
  <ul>
    {{#each item in controller.items}}
      <li>{{item.post_timestamp}}: {{{item.summary}}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/each}}
```

That code more-or-less does what I want: it renders the items, sorted by item.post_timestamp, as SubscriptionController defines it.

The problem is if I change `{{#each controller}}` to `{{#each site in user_sites}}`, the itemController property doesn't seem to magically apply to the sublist. Is there some kind of Sorcery I should use to inform Ember in my filters that I'd rather return the controller for the objects rather than the objects themselves?

EDITed to add: I know I can just add a new property like sorted_items on the Subscription model itself, but this feels wrong, design-wise. The model holds the data, the view shows the data, and the controller deals with sorting / filtering and all that jazz. Or at least that's part of how I think about MVC separation.

Comment: did you had a look at http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_filterBy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually set the `itemController` for loops.  You might try this in your template:

```
{{#each site in user_sites itemController="subscription"}}
...
{{/each}}
```