# EmberJS Sort / Filter an ArrayController decorated by an ObjectController

Tags: ember.js

I'm struggling with limiting a data set represented by an ArrayController that also relies upon an ObjectController as a decorator for actions and computed properties.  When I define a computed 'results' property and have it return either 'content' or 'arrangedContent', it seems my ObjectController (itemController) is entirely bypassed, and no references to the 'shipment' model are included.

Route:

```
App.ShipmentsManifestsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('manifest');
  }
})
```

Models:

```
App.Shipment = DS.Model.extend({
  from: DS.attr("string"),
  tracking: DS.attr("string"),
  manifest: DS.hasMany("manifest", { async: true   }),
  received: DS.attr("number", { 
    defaultValue: function() {
      return moment(Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
  })
});

App.Manifest = DS.Model.extend({
  upc:       DS.attr("string"),
  quantity:  DS.attr("number", { defaultValue: 1        }),
  condition: DS.attr("string", { defaultValue: 'New'    }),
  status:    DS.attr("string", { defaultValue: 'Accept' }),
  title:     DS.attr("string"),
  notes:     DS.attr("string"),
  shipment:  DS.belongsTo("shipment", { async: true }),
});
```

Controllers:

```
App.ManifestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      this.get('model').save();
    }
  },

  receivedDate: function() {
    return moment(this.get('shipment.received')).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  }.property('shipment.received')
})

App.ShipmentsManifestsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'manifest',
  sortProperties: ['shipment.received'],
  sortAscending: false,  

  results: function() {
    return this.get('arrangedContent').slice(0, 10);  
  }.property('arrangedContent.[]')  
})
```

Also worth noting is that my itemController actions essentially don't seem to exist when using 'results' to render my data set.  I have some inline editing functionality baked in that calls the 'save' action on the itemController, and Ember is throwing an error that 'save' doesn't exist.

This all of course works as it should if I iterate over {{#each controller}} rather than {{#each results}}.

I guess ultimately the problem is that 'content' doesn't return all of the data elements / properties / computed properties that would otherwise be available on the controller.

Is there a best practice way around this limitation?

UPDATE:

The problem is definitely related to the missing itemController when referencing arrangedContent.  When iterating over the ArrayController directly, my View is referencing App.ManifestController as the controller.  However, when iterating over arrangedContent, my View is instead referencing App.ShipmentsManifestsController as the controller.  Still unsure as to why that is.

UPDATE 2:

Based on this, it looks like my issue is a duplicate of [Setting itemController on a filtered subset of an ArrayController's model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665085/setting-itemcontroller-on-a-filtered-subset-of-an-arraycontrollers-model)

A work-around that involves additional handlebars parameters was offered, which I will try.  But would still love any input on whether this is intended behaviour or a bug.